# PyUSB, Device not found when I restart my program

Tags: python, usb

I have this small program that uses a USB Barcode scanner to read barcodes and display them to the console. Anytime I restart the program, I need to disconnect and reconnect the device or else I get a **usb.core.USBError: [Errno 19] No such device (it may have been disconnected)** error. Why is this the case and how can I make sure I don't need to reconnect the device each time?

Comment: use **cfg = dev.get_active_configuration()
if cfg is None or cfg.bConfigurationValue != cfg_desired:
    dev.set_configuration(cfg_desired)**